# Why hibernate persist() is slow? It is only slow in my case?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persist

I am trying to populate a database by creating entity objects and calling `persist()` using Hibernate as JPA provider.

At the beginning, the database is empty, then I am creating entity instances (100,000 instances) in a loop, and persist each one.

This operation take like 10 minutes to inject all the entities into the database.
I am using free tire amazon cloud server machine, 600 MB of RAM memory.

The loop is something like the follow:

```
@Transactional
void populateDataBase()
{
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        MyEntityPK entityInstancePK = new MyEntityPK(idfield1, idField2, idField3);

        MyEntity entityInstance = new MyEntity();

        entityInstance.setId(entityInstancePK);

        entityInstance.setField1(integerValue);
        entityInstance.setField2(integerValue);

        entityInstance.persist();
    }
}
```

If I comment the `persist()` line, the loop finish in few seconds. When I uncomment the `entityInstance.persist();` line, the loop take like 10 minutes to finish.

Is this operation is time and memory consuming? or it should not be fast?
Is calling merge() instead of persist() is better in this case? and quicker maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you need to check out the [documentation on batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).

You want to do something more like

```
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi hvgotcodes, I do not think that calling clear could help me. But calling flush() maybe will help. Thank you I will check your link. But what I thought, that the @Transactional function will manage this automatically (it will call flush() automatically).

Comment: its not the clear, its the flushing of the session so that you save more than 1 at once.